# Recursively iterate through a Scala list

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm trying to recursively iterate through a list in Scala using pattern matching. I cannot use any list functions, or while/for loops. What I need to do is iterate through the list, and remove an element if it matches to be '4'. I'm new to Scala and I cannot find the answer in the textbook I have nor on google. Everyone else uses the filter method, or some other list method.

Here's what I tried to do (which is wrong)

```
def removeFours(lst: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
val newLst = lst
lst match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case a if a == 4 => newLst -= 0
  case n => removeFours(newLst)
}
newLst
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```
def removeFours(lst: List[Int], acc: List[Int] = List.empty): List[Int] = {
  lst match {
     case Nil    => acc.reverse
     case 4 :: t => removeFours( t, acc )
     case h :: t => removeFours( t, h :: acc )
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> removeFours( List(3,7,4,9,2,4,1) )
res84: List[Int] = List(3, 7, 9, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an inner function and pattern matching to de-structure the list. If the head in the list is `4`, then do not add it to the accumulator. If it is, append it to the accumulator.

```
def removeFours(lst: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  def loop(lst: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = lst match {
    case Nil => acc
    case h :: t =>
      if (h == 4) {
        loop(t, acc)
      }else{
        loop(t, acc :+ h)
      }
  }
  loop(lst, List())
}
```

The preferred way to do this is with guards in the pattern match but the if else statement may look more familiar if you're just getting started with scala.

```
def removeFours(lst: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  def loop(lst: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = lst match {
    case Nil => acc
    case h :: t if (h == 4) => loop(t, acc)
    case h :: t  => loop(t, acc :+ h)
  }
  loop(lst, List())
}
```

Comment: add `@tailrec` annotation to the `loop` function to be sure that it doesn't eat stack. It won't in this case, but it is always a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the execution time. I am also new to scala but I am taking bollean approach to filter any list.

```
object Main extends App {
//fun that will remove 4
  def rm_4(lst: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
    val a = lst.filter(kill_4)
    a
  }
// boolean fun for conditions
  def kill_4(n: Int) : Boolean = {
    if (n ==4) false
    else true
  }
println(rm_4(List(1,2,4,5,4))) // outpur List(1,2,5)
}
```